# Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ a vector space or a metric space?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

In my various courses, for instance, linear algebra and vector calculus, I am somewhat confused with what precisely $\mathbb{R}^n$ is.

From the definition of the Cartesian product, I would conceptualise $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the metric space with some distance operator, where all the points are just $n$-tuples. This is surely a distinct notion from vectors as isn't the point $A = (1,2,3)$, for instance, different from the vector $\vec{a} =\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}$ ? But if we were to consider the points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as vectors then clearly it is a vector space. However I don't know whether these two conceptions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are actually equivalent. Surely the vectors do not correspond to a specific point in space, unlike the points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Forgive me if this is a silly question, or if my question seems garbled. Also please help me with tags if they are inappropriate.

Comment: Vectors do correspond to points in space. You may think of them arrows emanating from the origin ($0$ vector), if you want to see them as "vectors". Moreover, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a normed space, meaning we can assign a length to each vector, and from this length we get a metric. Now, there are some discrepancies between these two characterizations, specifically, the vector space structure is purely algebraic (it allows us to add, subtract, and scalar multiply points) whereas a metric/norm is more topology (giving us notions of nearness, convergence, closedness, etc)

Comment: it is also a Banach space, or a Hilbert space, or an affine space... It can be many things

Comment: @rubikscube09 This may seem silly but can't you then translate that position vector anywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and given that it has the same length and direction, won't it be the same vector? Or are you saying, rather, that it's almost like a game of hats: we choose to think of it as a metric space and as a vector space based upon what it is we are doing?

Comment: The arrows only make sense if they are coming from the origin. If you draw an arrow from one point to another, you are taking the vectorial difference of the two vectors, if they both had arrows starting from the origin. In general, it is much more helpful and useful to simply consider elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as points in $n$ space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a vector space is "a set together with an addition and a scalar multiplication for which the following properties hold..."

By itself (as a set) $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a vector space or a metric space.  When you lump it in with appropriate operations, then the triple $(\mathbb{R}^n,\cdot,+)$ is a vector space.  When you lump it in with an appropriate distance function, then $(\mathbb{R}^n, d(\cdot,\cdot))$ then you have a metric space.

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is just a set.  You have to add this or that structure to make it anything else.

Comment: So say, when finding limits in $\mathbb{R}^2$, why do we necessarily choose then to think of it as a metric space? Is it because there would be no notion of closeness if we were to think of it as a vector space? Or do we *not* necessarily choose to think of it as a metric space?

Comment: We're just usually a little informal.  There are lots of metrics and lots of vector additions we could put on the set of vectors, but if no one says otherwise, we usually assume it's the "usual" norm and vector addition.  So we have "both" a vector space and a metric space and do whatever is convenient.

Answer (score 2):

It is both a vector space and a metric space. Yes, a space can be both of them! And even more interestingly, it's an inner product space which means that we can measure angles in it. This is why $\mathbb{R}^n$ is so useful in geometry.

It's a vector space from an algebraic point of view. It's a metric space from an analytic point of view. Both of these views work together, hand in hand, to make mathematics more interesting than just a bunch of abstract definitions.